# Want to build a camera app which can have Custom capture area on camera view

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I want to capture a particular area from the camera.

I can build the custom preview, but that is not my actual requirement.

i want to have viewfinder like capture area on camera view and that should be the captured image size.

Comment: So you want to crop the preview, and crop the captured image?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this a month back. The captured image or the preview image will not be pre-cropped. The trick is to identify your viewfinders rect and apply crop on the captured image.

You can head over to GitHub and clone my project [Shaili-Android](https://github.com/awanishraj/Shaili-Android).
You will find the relevant camera code in [`CameraActivity.java`](https://github.com/awanishraj/Shaili-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/in/ac/iitm/shaili/Activities/CameraActivity.java)

I have documented the project religiously. If you have issues, comment below.

Hope this helps :)